# How do I add a second attribute in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, attributes, jvectormap, stroke

I am currently working with a jvectormap.  Each county has a data-code (example: 48201).  Here is my code for the counties that I have colored so far...

```
jvm.Map.maps = {};
jvm.Map.defaultParams = {
  map: 'us_lcc_en',series: {
        regions: [{
            values: {
```

/* --------------- Active Franchise --------------- */

```
                '42029':'#eb2e4d',
                '42091':'#eb2e4d',
                '42101':'#eb2e4d',
                '42045':'#eb2e4d',
                '42017':'#eb2e4d',
                '42077':'#eb2e4d',
                '42095':'#eb2e4d',
                '48085':'#eb2e4d',
                '48113':'#eb2e4d',
                '48439':'#eb2e4d',
                '48121':'#eb2e4d',
```

/* --------------- Available Franchise --------------- */

```
                '42129':'#5d9eec',
                '42007':'#5d9eec',
                '42125':'#5d9eec',
                '42019':'#5d9eec',
                '42003':'#5d9eec',
                '13067':'#5d9eec',
                '13121':'#5d9eec',
                '13057':'#5d9eec',
                '13135':'#5d9eec',
                '13089':'#5d9eec',
                '13063':'#5d9eec',
                '13151':'#5d9eec',
                '13297':'#5d9eec',
                '13117':'#5d9eec',
                '48339':'#5d9eec',
                '48201':'#5d9eec',
                '48157':'#5d9eec',
                '48167':'#5d9eec',
                '48039':'#5d9eec',
                '48029':'#5d9eec',
                '48187':'#5d9eec',
                '48091':'#5d9eec',
                '04013':'#5d9eec',
                '09003':'#5d9eec',
                '09013':'#5d9eec',
                '09001':'#5d9eec',
                '09009':'#5d9eec',
                '09007':'#5d9eec',
                '09005':'#5d9eec',
```

/* --------------- Pending Franchise --------------- */

```
                '48491':'#83a85d',
                '48453':'#83a85d',
                '48209':'#83a85d',

            },

            attribute:'fill',
            "stroke-width": 4

        }]

    },
  backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
  zoomButtons: true,
  zoomOnScroll: false,
  panOnDrag: true,
  zoomMax: 8,
  zoomMin: 1,
  zoomStep: 1.6,
  zoomAnimate: true,
  regionsSelectable: false,
  markersSelectable: false,
  bindTouchEvents: true,
  regionStyle: {
    initial: {
      fill: 'rgb(204, 204, 204)',
      "fill-opacity": 1,
      stroke: 'rgb(204, 204, 204)',
      "stroke-width": 0,
      "stroke-opacity": 1,
    },
    hover: {
      "fill-opacity": 0.7,
      cursor: 'pointer'
    },
    selected: {
      fill: 'yellow'
    },
    selectedHover: {
    }
  },
  regionLabelStyle: {
    initial: {
      'font-family': 'Verdana',
      'font-size': '12',
      'font-weight': 'bold',
      cursor: 'default',
      fill: 'black',
    },
    hover: {
      cursor: 'pointer'
    }
  },
  markerStyle: {
    initial: {
      fill: 'grey',
      stroke: '#505050',
      "fill-opacity": 1,
      "stroke-width": 1,
      "stroke-opacity": 1,
      r: 5
    },
    hover: {
      stroke: 'black',
      "stroke-width": 2,
      cursor: 'pointer'
    },
    selected: {
      fill: 'blue'
    },
    selectedHover: {
    }
  },
  markerLabelStyle: {
    initial: {
      'font-family': 'Verdana',
      'font-size': '12',
      'font-weight': 'bold',
      cursor: 'default',
      fill: 'black'
    },
    hover: {
      cursor: 'pointer'
    }
  }
};
jvm.Map.apiEvents = {
  onRegionTipShow: 'regionTipShow',
  onRegionOver: 'regionOver',
  onRegionOut: 'regionOut',
  onRegionClick: 'regionClick',
  onRegionSelected: 'regionSelected',
  onMarkerTipShow: 'markerTipShow',
  onMarkerOver: 'markerOver',
  onMarkerOut: 'markerOut',
  onMarkerClick: 'markerClick',
  onMarkerSelected: 'markerSelected',
  onViewportChange: 'viewportChange'
};
```

As you can see at the bottom...the attribute is set to 'fill'.  I also want to add 'stroke'.  How do I go about adding that second attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attributes in a javaScript object are separated by commas. Suppose you wanted to add a stroke-width attribute:

In this case, you would change the tail end, near the bottom, to look something like this:

```
            '48491':'#83a85d',
            '48453':'#83a85d',
            '48209':'#83a85d',

        },
        attribute: 'fill',
        stroke-width: 4
    }]
},
```

Which should make you happy. Though, as an aside, stroke-width will actually be the third attribute of 'regions': you'll note that values is written in the form of "values: {...}," -- it's an attribute too!

Comment: So say I wanted to give the same color stroke as the fill of each county with a stroke size of 4...How would I write that out?  Thank you for your response btw!

Comment: I'm not familiar with jVectorMap specifically, but I looked up its documentation and edited my answer to show an example of changing the stroke width. Hopefully, it'll work! "Same color stroke as the fill of each county" may be a bit more difficult than you think, however, since you aren't defining the color of those fills, just letting the library pick for you, I believe.

Comment: That's what I thought and I thought this would work but sadly it doesn't :(  Here's the code in context...

Comment: When I change attribute:'fill', to attribute:'stroke' then the stroke works but the fill is no longer there.  I just need both at the same time haha.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13344196/is-there-a-way-to-use-fill-and-stroke-as-attribute-for-regions-scale-colors This question seems to have what you need!